# Does Google Schema support quoted-printable encoding?

Tags: email, mandrill, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm trying to [self-test](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema#self_testing) my email schemas.

My mail is sent with:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

The original script tag `<script type="application/ld+json">` is rendered as `<script type=3D"application/ld+json">`, when I *View Original* the marked up email.

This fails the [markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester), but when I manually remove the **3D**, it passes the test.

Q1 - Does Google support `quoted-printable` encoding?

Q2 - Why does the test fail?

Note: On a Rails application I use the Mandrill API to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Yes, quoted-printable is supported.

2.) You're testing the markup after it had been encoded. You should [decode](http://www.webatic.com/run/convert/qp.php) the raw email, then [test it](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester).

Comment: Enable to visible/ work email markup code when I attach an attachment with email.
Please help me.