# Gmail ignores metadata for hotel reservation

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to fix the data that gmail pulls automatically from my emails by supplying the right metadata but gmail ignores it and still shows the wrong checkout date.

[image: Mismatched data]

I've read through some similar issues found here and I do have the PASS status for DKIM and SPF headers.

[image: DKIM and SPF results]

Comment: i see an error at `<script type=3D"application/ld+json...`  the `3D` seems to be an encoding problem? you need to remove it

Comment: That is the source of the email in gmail and it is `quoted-printable`. I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117291/does-google-schema-support-quoted-printable-encoding that this is supported and not an issue

Answer (score 0):

ok i had another look on this and referring to [LodgingReservation schema](https://schema.org/LodgingReservation)

you have to use

`checkinTime & checkoutTime` properties instead of `checkinDate`

should work then ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I just tried this and unfortunately got the same results. I noticed that google's validator wants `checkinDate` and `checkoutDate`.

Comment: you are right, thats a bit inconsistent, so only thing left for me is that your date-strings are not propper ISO8601 formatted (the `z` at the and must be uppercase `Z` i guess, referring to https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/datetime-formatting)

Comment: It is uppercase :)